# Can't locate error origin

Tags: java, android, exception

I get this weird error in my MainActivity, can't reproduce it myself but this is what I get in Crash report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65538, result=0, data=null} to activity {lv.mobi.android/lv.mobi.android.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3455)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3498)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at lv.mobi.android.b.aj.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(Unknown Source)
at lv.mobi.android.MainActivity.onActivityResult(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3451)
        ... 11 more
```

I thought it could be something in **onActivityResult**, but can't figure out what, my result function doesn't have much in it:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int _requestCode, int _resultCode, Intent _data) {
    super.onActivityResult(_requestCode, _resultCode, _data);
    if(_resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){
        reloadUser();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at lv.mobi.android.b.aj.a(Unknown Source)` - find out where this is in your code. (It's obfuscated because you turned on obfuscation.)

Comment: what does reloadUser() do ? Can you post the code ?

Comment: You should add some `log.d ()` calls to locate yourself.

Comment: @immibis I can't see precise error line because of zipalign ?

Comment: @somerandomusername You can't see the precise error line because of ProGuard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my guess, you need to put below code

```
 if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED){
    if(_resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){
       reloadUser();
    }
 }
```

Because you are cancelling that activity/process due to that intent is getting null value.

Answer (score 0):

For what i can see and based on the comments. It's a NullPointerException, witch means some where in your code you are not initializing a variable / class or something is returning null. If you like to read up on it to get a better understanding here is a link [NullPointerException Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html), also it would help to post some of your code.

Comment: Thank you, I know about NullPointerException. But what confuses me is that I can't see where it occurs. I guess it's perhaps because I'm obfuscating my application ?

Comment: Have you tried RIT solution? And if yes did it work? Also it is a good idea to try to keep your code as neat as possible, so that it is much easier to read and it can also help you in the debugging process.

Comment: I can't test now for sure, as I can't reproduce this error. Only way is to update app and see if crash reports keep coming in.